Android Studio disconnects from ADB
I have been facing issue for sometime now. I use ubuntu for development but now the issue I face - Whenever I run adb commands on terminal, Android Studio disconnects weird though I can install the apps via run but logcat, layout inspector which I use frequently would show device as offline.
The issue can be resolved if I reopen Android Studio but it's kinda hindering my flow of development.
Has anyone faced something similar

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/adb-constantly-disconnects-shows-device-offline

I did take a look at this link before and the solutions did not work for me

Find how many adb you have installed (it may take some time):
find / -type f -name adb -ls 2>/dev/null

compare their version and check which one is used by your shell
type adb

and make your shell and AS use the same.

Using the first command I do see that there are a few different paths. And for type adb it returns usr/bin/adb
I believe AS use Android SDK platform tools under home directory

Finally after some figuring out and removing extra adb paths. It worked!
Thanks for leading me in the right direction
